# How to use Plivo PHP helper libraries without composer

Tags: php, plivo

I'm trying to use the Plivo PHP helper library in my project, but looks like the only way to use it is with Composer. Is there any work around for this since I cannot use composer in my project as it would change the existing code?

Comment: Hi,
I'm not sure how it would change your code. Composer should only handle the downloading and auto loading of dependencies. The alternative option is you find the dependencies yourself, download and include them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

Unfortunately, Plivo-PHP helper library can be used only with Composer. If installing the library with Composer is not feasible, you could download and install the dependencies individually and include the libraries in your project. Or, you could also make HTTP requests to the API directly without using the helper library. You could use cURL or Requests library to make these requests.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

The access to the server was very limited, I had only FTP access, I could have waited to ask for SSH access to do the install using composer I simply installed Composer on my local machine and then just had to run

```
composer require plivo/php-sdk
```

In an empty directory. It created the SDK files under `/vendor` and I uploaded those files through FTP to the server. Did the job for me.